# Java times table

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I want to try to make this kind of output but my code is having some errors. Would it be best to use an if/else statement below, or use another loop?

**Here is my desired output:**

```
Do you wish to continue >> Y  
Please enter the integer >> 2  
table 2 

1 x 2 = 2 

2 x 2 = 4 

... 

12 x 2 = 24  

Do you want to continue >> T
```

**Here is my current code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tugas6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int pilihan;
        int i, j;

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue >>");
        pilihan = input.nextInt();

        if (pilihan == y)

            System.out.println("Please enter the integer >>");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        j = in .nextInt();

        System.out.println("table" + j);

        for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            System.out.println(+i + "*" + j + " = " + (i * j));

        else(pilihan == t)
        System.out.println("Thank you");
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: What is your question exactly? First of all 'y' isn't an integer.

Comment: You're missing a bracket after `if (pilihan==y)`

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues, first character literals should be surrounded with `''` characters. Next your `if` needs a code block (braces) because it consists of multiple statements. You don't need `in` because you have `input`. So, your code should be something like,

```
if (pilihan=='y') {
  System.out.println("Please enter the integer >>");
  j = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("table" +j);
  for ( i = 1 ; i <= 12 ; i++ )
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + "*"+j+" = "+(i*j));
} else if (pilihan=='t') {
  System.out.println("Thank you");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it Simple

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class table{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         String choice;
         int i, j;
         System.out.println("Do you want to continue >>");
         choice = input.next();
         if(choice.equals("y")){
             System.out.println("Please enter the integer >>");
             j = input.nextInt();
             System.out.println("table" +j);
             for( i = 1 ; i <= 12 ; i++ ){
                 System.out.println(i+"*"+j+" = "+(i*j));
             }
         }else{
             System.out.println("Thank you");
         }
     }
}
```

You should have to go through the basics of data types and comparison using if condition on int and String and you dont have to define two Scanners.

Answer (score 0):

I would for the most part agree with krnaveen14, but with one small change. Since "y" is not the same as "Y", and I assume you want them to be the same, add .toLowerCase to the .equlas part of the method.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String pilihan = "";
  int i, j;
  System.out.println("Do you want to continue >>");
  pilihan = input.next();
  if (pilihan.toLowerCase().equals("y"))
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter the integer >>");
    j = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("table" +j);
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 12 ; i++ )
         System.out.println(+i+"*"+j+" = "+(i*j));
    }
 else
    System.out.println("Thank you");

}
```